# Generalization of Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have learned that Every Bounded Sequence has a convergent subsequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric.
Can I extend this result for any Metric Space by introducing some more conditions?

One thing that I have observed is, if we take X to be an infinite set and define the discrete metric in it then we can easily construct sequences that are monotone but they do not have any subsequence that converge.
E.g. Take $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete metric and consider the sequence $1,2,3,....$ this itself is a monotone sequence but this does not converge anywhere.

Comment: What is a monotone sequence in an arbitrary infinite set?

Comment: any two consecutive points are mapped to a real number by the definition of the metric and using that we can say some sequence is monotone

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be generalised.

The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (for $\Bbb R$) can be restated as: "closed and bounded intervals/sets are sequentially compact". For if $(a_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence, I can view it as a sequence in $[-M,M]$ for some $M>0$ and sequential compactness of that interval tells me $(a_n)_n$ converges along some subsequence.

General Bolzano-Weierstrass-Heine-Borel theorem:

> For a metric space, the following are equivalent: (i) the space is compact (ii) the space is sequentially compact (iii) the space is complete and **totally** bounded

It is a nice exercise to try to understand this equivalence (show that $(i)\implies(ii)\implies(iii)\implies(i)$). This contains the Heine-Borel and Bolzano-Weierstrass theorems for $\Bbb R^n$ since in $\Bbb R^n$, a set is bounded iff. it is totally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The nice exercise suggested by FSbrike is minimal for studing Analysis.
I observe that, if I am not wrong, in N with the discrete metric, only the sequences eventually constant are convergent. The sequence 1,2,3..n.. is not bounded so BW theorem does not apply. A point of N is open, so the set of all points is an open cover of N that has not a finite subcover of N: N is not compact.